# Fortran, Meaning of Unary* operator in function calls?

Tags: syntax, fortran, fortran77, unary-operator

I am attempting to make modifications to an old fortran code to get it to handle a slightly different binary input file format. In the process of doing this I have been encountering * used in a unary fashion. For example, this code found within a loop:

```
          CALL EVENT1(QDRBUF(IPNTR+EVTHSZ),EVTSIZ,EVTID,                
     -                                            *11000,*10000,*80000)
```

There are other cases as well but as far as I have seen / remember it is only in function calls. What is this doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fortran return statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214059/fortran-return-statement)

Comment: I would argue it is the same topic, but not a duplicate question.

Comment: I agree with Vladimir. The answers to the question you suggest this to be a duplicate of, do answer my question, but the question itself is not duplicated. Their question is about the return statement, mine is about the function call. As Vladimir said, same topic different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Fortran guy, but this question intrigued me, so I did some looking. It appears to be an [alternate return specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214149/10077). The number after the asterisk is a label that can be used in place of a normal return, almost like catching an exception.

Comment: Thanks, most of my coding is in cpp and python so on the rare times when i work with fortran code some aspects of the syntax occasionally make me grind to halt since i don't even know what to call them when searching the Internet. It didn't even occur to me that people might put what are effectively goto labels as function parameters. Thanks again.

Comment: This is correct. You add a number (1, 2, etc.) to the RETURN statement to indicate which of the alternate statement numbers (not line numbers) control resumes at at the return.