# What the asterisk * symbol mean in a Fortran subroutine argument list?

Tags: fortran, return, arguments, label, subroutine

What does the * mean as the argument in the subroutine? Does it mean a label and it returns to main program? is it related to `return`, `return 1`, `ERR` or `ERROR`? I don't know why we have these, but I think that asterisk is related to them.

```
  !>Start the creation of boundary conditions for the equation set.
SUBROUTINE  BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_CREATE_START(SOLVER_EQUATIONS,BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS,ERR,ERROR,*)

!Argument variables
INTEGER(INTG), INTENT(OUT) :: ERR !<The error code
TYPE(VARYING_STRING), INTENT(OUT) :: ERROR !<The error string
!Local Variables
TYPE(VARYING_STRING) :: LOCAL_ERROR

ENTERS("BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_CREATE_START",ERR,ERROR,*999)

    IF(ASSOCIATED(BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS)) THEN
      CALL FlagError("Boundary conditions is already associated.",ERR,ERROR,*999)
    ELSE
      IF(ASSOCIATED(SOLVER_EQUATIONS%SOLVER_MAPPING)) THEN
        !Initialise the boundary conditions
        CALL BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_INITIALISE(SOLVER_EQUATIONS,ERR,ERROR,*999)
      ELSE
        LOCAL_ERROR="Solver equations solver mapping is not associated."
        CALL FlagError(LOCAL_ERROR,ERR,ERROR,*999)
      ENDIF
    ENDIF
  ENDIF

EXITS("BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_CREATE_START")
RETURN
999 ERRORSEXITS("BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_CREATE_START",ERR,ERROR)
RETURN 1
END SUBROUTINE BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_CREATE_START
```

Comment: Is this related...? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnb3/index.html

Comment: Please use [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention. Compare the number of followers of tags [tag:fortran] and [tag:fortran95]. Your question is not version specific.

Comment: We can try to close it, I can move my answer there. But I can no longer instaclose this one because I had to edit the tag. Many people come to the question, but they don't fix the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a label for the *alternate return* from the function. It is the label where the function can eventually return to when using

```
 return 1
```

instead of

```
return
```

which returns to the location from which the subroutine was called.

This feature is strongly discouraged for new code although I have seen a proposal how to use this code for a kind of exceptions.

Very related question, almost a duplicate (asking for the return statement instead):  [Fortran return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214059/fortran-return-statement)

Comment: It is actually a FORTRAN 66 feature. It has been labeled as "obsolescent" since Fortran 90, but remains in the standard as of Fortran 2015. (The committee has been more reluctant to actually delete features, especially as vendors complain that they still have to support them and deletion means there is no text explaining how they work with other features.)

Comment: If this is code you can change, refactor away the alternate return ASAP. It's one of the "kill it with fire" features of F66 that shows up very rarely even in old code; it should never be in new code. Better to return a status code which is handled by the calling routine. It's an insignificant amount of extra code to write but it is far, far clearer.